# OpenCV gaussian blur is slow on android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am writing an android application which applies gaussian blur on an image using OpenCV, however, it is very slow.

```
// Gaussian blur sample code
cv::Mat output;
chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
chrono::duration<int, std::milli> duration;

cv::GaussianBlur(<input>, output, cv::Size(25, 25), 0, 0);

duration = chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - t1);
printf("%d", duration.count()); // Displays ~10-15 ms
```

When I measure the time taken by this API, it always comes ~10-15 ms. Does anyone have any idea why it's so slow on android?

Comment: What does this mean: `API, it always comes ~10-15 ms.`? Booting up?

Comment: I meant the time taken by just this one GaussianBlur() call. Added more code to clarify. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yeah. I do not know why you are measuring other than to show how sow it is. How are you loading OpenCV? I would do it the beginning, long before you ran any of your JNI code.

Comment: What are you comparing it to?

Comment: I'm comparing it with other phones e.g. iPhone. The very same API takes very less time to apply gaussian blur.

Answer (score 1):

The questions is lacking some data, because 'Android' means nothing: how big is the image? Which phone are you using? Are you using the stock build, or are you building it yourself? A 25x25 kernel is quite big.

If you're using the stock Android build on an armv7-a phone, with a big image (a few megapixels), it's probably expected. The stock Android build of OpenCV doesn't use NEON, and doesn't use multithreading, which will help a lot. Also, most Android phones are much slower than iPhones (specially 5s and 6) on single core processes, and they tend to reduce the CPU clocks to save battery and avoid thermal issues.

I suggest you build OpenCV yourself with NEON enabled and give it a try.

Comment: Image is of size approx 350x350. I'm using nexus 7 and stock build of opencv. I tried building OpenCV with NEON enabled and I couldn't see any improvement. It looks like this GaussianBlur() is probably not optimized for NEON. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this the nexus 7 2012? That's a slow device. 2013 is better, but will still be slow. The latest OpenCV 3 had a lot of NEON code added. Is that the one you're using?

Comment: In OpenCV 4.0 it DO USE neon now! Yeah! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041536/opencv-4-0-android-ndk-with-neon-why-and-why-not