# OpenCV 4.0 Android (NDK) With NEON: Why And Why Not?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, simd

I am using the OpenCV for Android NDK, which can be downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.0/opencv-4.1.0-android-sdk.zip/download), and I just use the `libopencv_java4.so`.

It seems that **it is not compiled with NEON** (correct me if I am wrong). However, IMHO, `NEON`, the SIMD architecture, can dramatically speed up the library. On the other hand, I think if the people in OpenCV decide to compile without NEON, there must be a big reason. Therefore, I am hoping for advice about:

1. Shall I compile with NEON?
2. Will NEON boost up the speed (I think yes?) ?
3. What are the disadvantages of compiling with NEON, if any? (i.e. Why OpenCV does not compile with NEON by default?)

I would truly appreciate it for any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: The disadvantage would be that it won't run on CPUs that don't support NEON. No idea how common those are.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for suggestion! However, will/can it just *fallback* to normal mode instead lf not runming?

Comment: If you want to fallback to non-NEON code, you need to search for CPU dispatching. I'm no expert in that, especially not for ARM.

Comment: @chtz Thank you all the same!

Comment: It seems that, judging from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake, the `arm64-v8a` will ENABLE neon, while `armeabi-v7a` will NOT (unless you compile with `armeabi-v7a with NEON`. I am confused about the down-compatibility and so on, but I think for newer machines (with arm64v8a) the neon should **be enabled**.